# React Native TabNavigator this.props.navigation.state.params is undefined

Tags: android, react-native, navigator, tabnavigator

I'm making an android app using react native. I'm tring to pass params throught TabNavigator, but the 
this.props.navigation.state.params is undefined. Currently I'm using:

```
"react-native": "0.51.0",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.22"
```

Example code (tried to keep the relevant only):

this is my index.js:

```
const RootNavigator = TabNavigator({
    Home: { screen: App },
    Design: { screen: ImageDesign }
}
```

this is the home screen:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { ... }
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarVisible: false
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="design image"
                onPress={ () => navigate('Design',{name: 'Jane'}) }/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

this is the design screen:

```
export default class ImageDesign extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { ... }
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarVisible: false
  };

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{ params.name }</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

but unfortunately params is undefined, so an 'undefined is not an object' error accured

I also tried:

```
<Button title="design image"
        onPress={ () => navigate('Design', {}, {type: "Navigate", routName:"ImageDesign", params: {name: 'Jane'}}) }/>
```

but I'm not sure that works that way

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just try `this.props.name`. The params/props should be sent as a prop. You shouldn't need to access the navigation state like that.